# Reading SQL query from external file in DAO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

In my spring boot application I have my query in an external file (`sql.properties`) and reading it in `DAO`

```
@Value("${queries.selectValue}") 
private String selectQuery;
```

Is this the right way ? Any security issues here

Comment: It's right if your query is static and you need to change it without recompiling your app.

Comment: Yes it's right. No security issue .

Comment: Gracias @htpvl and Raheela